# Where can I find the diplomatic relationships of the nations in the Sixth Coalition?

Tags: napoleonic-wars

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Sixth_Coalition) page I can see which side each nation was on, but it does not mean that each country was in war with all the nations on the other site. Let me give an example: Denmark-Norway was allied with Napoleon and in war with United Kingdom and Sweden I know, but it does not mean that Denmark-Norway was in war with **all** of the nations from the Sixth Coalition. For example they were not at war with Prussia (which was a member of the Sixth Coalition).

Where can I find the diplomacy relationship of the nations in that period ?

Comment: So basically, you are looking for a matrix.

Comment: Yes or just some of the entries in the matrix would also be ok.